# Word Underline does not print

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

Underline shows on print preview, but does not print on the paper or when printed as image.

I know it has to do with textbox settings, because when i create new text box it prints fine, however i want to find what exact setting is causing this.

Uploaded document [here](https://www.upload.ee/files/14552761/Doc2.zip.html).

Answer (score 0):

This text box has no underline in it.

The line you see is the bottom border of the text box, which is defined as
having only the bottom border.

According to my tests, for some unknown reason Word will not print the
bottom border of a text box if all four borders were not specified.
This is perhaps a Word bug.

Comment: Underline is within Paragraph not a text box border. 
I found a solution if i set Text Box Vertical alignment - "top" it does print underline, however its beyond me why this has any effect.
Also if i set "resize shape to fit text" then it also prints underline.

Seems like also setting bottom or top margin for text box until underline is right below text also makes line print.